# How to programmatically monitor Windows swap space usage in real time?

Tags: windows, memory, swap

I can write a program by using wmi to monitor the space usage of a hard drive. What should I do about swap memory usage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Win32_PageFileUsage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394246%28VS.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [Sysinternal's Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/sysinternals/bb896653)